# In LineChart, Is it possible to set a specific color between values? Like if the value increased or decreased (Green/Red)

Tags: android, charts, colors, mpandroidchart

Im wondering if this is possible

[image]

So I can change the color between 2 values if the next value increased or decreased

EDIT: Following anhtuannd code, it gave me this error

[Error in "If"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHB9V.png)

I tried to do a work arround with different operator but the only working was "==" but it is not what I look for

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.

You can create new array of color (arrayColor[n-1]) that its size equals to number of points (n) minus 1. Then traverse from point 2 to the last point n. If point (i) is large than point (i-1), then the color at position i-1 is up color, otherwise is down color. Then you can use API lineDataSet.setColors(arrayColor);

Pseudo code:

```
int arrayColor[] = new int[]{};
for (int i = 1; i < lineDataSet.getValues().size(); i++) {
    if (lineDataSet.getValues().get(i) > lineDataSet.getValues().get(i-1)) {
         arrayColor[i-1] = UP_COLOR;
    } else { 
         arrayColor[i-1] = DOWN_COLOR;
    }
}

lineDataSet.setColors(arrayColor);
```

Comment: cool, just that it gave this error in set1.getValues().get(i) > set1.getValues().get(i-1) I eddited the post with an image

Comment: because it's pseudo code, so you have to rewrite it as actual Java/Kotlin code. I guess you have to replace `lineDataSet.getValues().get(i)` to `lineDataSet.getValues().get(i).getX()` or `lineDataSet.getValues().get(i).getY()`

Comment: Yes indeed, it was set1.getValues().get(k).getX() 
but now it give this error 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
I've already try to work it arround but no success, Im sure that the set is filled with data before doing this and tried the several options within .setColors. And even If I fill it manually with the Colors, it give me the same error but instead length=0; index=0 is length=2; index=2. Any thoughs?

Comment: Moreover, you have to give size to array when you create it.